# Parameterization of a cone

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have a cone that I need to parameterize, so that I can compute the flow through it, but I am stuck. I have a feeling that I just need to add a 2 somewhere to the standard parameterization, but i'm not sure.  what would the parameterization of the following cone be? I would also appreciate an explanation.

It is a cone with vertex $(0,0,2)^T$ base centered at point $(0,0,0)^T$ and radius $r=2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the cone is symmetric around the $z$ axis and that the line connecting the point $(0,0,2)$ to the point $(2,0,0)$ is on the face of the cone.

The line connecting these two points relates the $z$ coordinate with the radius of the circle at height $z$ defining the cone: at height $z$ the radius is $2-z$.

Thus the cone is parametrized by
$$x^2+y^2=(2-z)^2$$